# State API doesn't work on new paragraph fields

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I have programmatically added #states into fields in a paragraph works fine for existing fields in a form. But on clicking add more button on paragraph to add more fields the hidden fields show up. I tried this [Patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-16/2946856-do-not-show-hidden-elements.patch) but it didn't work for me.

I have used this hook to alter the field to add #states.

```php
function mymodule_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $element['subform']['field_title']['#states'] = [
    'invisible' => [
      '#edit-parent-field-0-subform-parent-field-content-'.$element['#delta'].'-subform-target-field-wrapper select' => ['value' => 'value']
    ]  
  ];
}
```

Comment: This patch is no longer necessary, this is already included in stable. If the code doesn't work, one of your selectors is incorrect.

Comment: But the same code works perfectly fine on initial page load. only fails when we try to add a new paragraph.

Comment: I guess when we add a new paragraph the form rebuilds but fails to implement the #states. I tried to print a variable into this hook and it worked to check if this hook is called on ajax call or not. But yes it is been called still the #states code doesnt work.

Comment: Just a blind guess, but if it works intially and not for newly added paragraphs, then the zero in `edit-parent-field-0-subform-parent-field-content` looks suspicious

Comment: Thanks  for this comment. I tried different approach changed the selector to select[name="field_parent[0][subform][field_parent_content][0][subform][field_target_field]"]. And its working perfectly fine now.